# pen drive removed while copying files

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, embedded

I am programing in C language (in an embedded environment). USB can be connected to that device. Now when I am copying files from USB to that device through my code then in between if someone removes the pendrive then how can we detect the removal of pendrive or how to handle this situation.

Device architecture : ARM , Linux Platform

I can check through whether the file is completely copied or not by comparing the file size in the source from where it was copied and the destination where it is supposed to be copied.
But pls let me know any other approach to ensure that file is copied successfully or not(if pendrive removed in between). Iam copying like this :

```
 sprintf(str, "cp %s%s /mnt/disk/.;sync", FILE_OP_PATH, name);
 96                 system(str);
```

Comment: You get hotplug block events for device attachment/removal. These can trigger mount/unmount and you can also find out how to hook into them to clean up in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a low-level error, the file-system will also be left in an unclean state and should be verified too.

Is this going to be expected method of operations or a more rare error-like event?

If it's a test case, just make sure your code does not explode or do other strange things like infinite loop retrying the write. The file-system on the device may also be left in an unclean state, since you are talking USB I'm thinking VFAT. Wrong file-sizes may be reported.

Comment: If the USB device was only being read from, I think it should be pretty safe. You might want to investigate if the filesystem does any access-time-tracking, though.

Comment: @unwind: Good point on the read, mounting it read-only would make the procedure quite safe. But I read it as it was going to be write ops.

Comment: @john: Then I would think just handling the situation and doing length/checksum validation on the drive being returned would do. You might want to consider write caching, it may be that you got no data at all transferred to the USB memory.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the system call(s) you're doing (either directly or indirectly through the standard library) will fail if the source device suddenly goes missing.

If you're using plain old `read()` to read from the USB drive, I would espect it to fail and set `errno`  to `EIO`, as the documentation states:

> It may also occur when there is a low-level I/O error while reading from a disk or tape.

Having the drive forcibly unmounted mid-read sounds like a "low-level I/O error" to me.

It's probably easiest to first detect the failure as per above, which of course your copying code will already do, and then as a follow-up try to come up with a diagnosis of what went wrong and caused the error, you can probably inspect the mounting table to see if the device is still around.

Answer (score 0):

Though my solution is slow, you can try `if(fopen("myfile", "r")!=NULL)` every to copy :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use and configure `udev` to be notified when something is plugged or unplugged on the USB port.